# Facebook is considering our website URL as Invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, facebook-ads

When we are trying to add our website URLs
https://taiwan.kisan.app and https://taiwan.kisan.in
in the Facebook advertisement.

We are getting the following error.

> Invalid link URL Provided: The link URL https://taiwan.kisan.app used
> in the Ad is invalid. Please use a different URL and try again.
> (#2490193)

We are not able to understand what is causing this error
as our site has SSL and it can be browsed from the browser
without error.

The site is hosted on Apache, AWS EC2 instance and there is a load balancer before EC2.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an URL shortener service like bit.ly to quickly resolve this. You can also have custom URL tag if you want. See [Bit.ly Sign Up](https://bitly.com/a/sign_up)

Comment: I do not want to use third-party short links.

Comment: Even when using the url shortener it will not solve.  Received a `This webpage contains a blocked URL.`

Answer (score 0):

You might try running your website through the Facebook Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

This tool was built to help to identify any errors that Facebook is reading from your website, and help provide information on what needs to be fixed to unblock your link.

From there, you can get help from your developers team or from the Facebook Developers team to make your website compliant and help our systems detect it as safe. Click the link below and select "Get Started" to open a support ticket with the Facebook Developers team (this option may not be available for all websites):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

The error may also occur because the URL is already being used by another Facebook page –possibly a forgotten page, previous page, or an unofficial, unverified page that was created by someone else

Comment: @Lucaz: When I am trying to add the URL on Facebook debug tool, getting the error. `We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know.`

Comment: Okay, not sure if it will help but filling in the `let us know` is a way to try and solve. 
Explain that you dont violated the Community Standards.
Can be a mistake from their end. 
To have more luck on receiving a response ask your friends to fill in the form aswell. I dont think FB will answer when only 1 person fills in the form. 
Good luck.

Comment: Any idea on "What exactly is expected in the site to comply with Facebook's Community Standards?"

Comment: @AmolChakane Have a look here: https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/
First glance on your website does not show any violations.

Comment: Ohh, that is plenty of content to read. :(